# How can I use a MySQL query in an openquery query on Microsoft SQL Server.?

Tags: sql-server, mysql

I have the following query which works fine in MySQL:

```
DELETE sb 
FROM stockbatches sb 
    INNER JOIN batchestodelete btd 
ON sb.batch_batch = btd.batchno 
    AND sb.batch_part = btd.batchpart
```

What I want to do is run this query on the MySQL table from SQL Server using an `openquery` to a linked MySQL server.  I cannot get the syntax right.

Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [OPENQUERY syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx) you'd have to rewrite the script in the following way:

```
DELETE OPENQUERY (MySQLServer, '
    SELECT sb.*
    FROM stockbatches sb 
    INNER JOIN batchestodelete btd 
    ON sb.batch_batch = btd.batchno 
    AND sb.batch_part = btd.batchpart;
');
```

Comment: Would that be the same if the batchestodelete file is on the local machine and stockbatches is on the linked server?

Comment: Not exactly identical... Then you'd have to build a query using tables' (4 part name)[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx].